# Can a family member use my iPhone, or does Touch ID lock them out on the iPhone SE?

Tags: iphone, user-account, touch-id

Can we bypass TouchID? I'm getting an iPhone SE and wondering if I can let my kids/family members use my phone if they need to?

I don't know much about Touch ID and am wondering if it can be bypassed, or if I can turn it off so they can use it to call? Also, does Touch ID support multiuser accounts if each person wants their own **profile**?

Comment: When you say "turn if off so they can use it to call" are you wanting to allow your kids *full* access to your iPhone or just the phone features?  You might want to check out [Parental Controls](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304#allow-apps)

Comment: Just phone features and apps. I would like kids or adults who are using the phone to make phone calls if they need to.  They're at the age where they are responsible enough to use it to call for help, or other adults if they need something. I don't want them to buy anything and plan not to store my creditcard details on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your device without enabling TouchID/FaceID.

iPhones (and iPads) are designed for a single user. iOS is unfortunately not multiuser.

With TouchID, you *could* train one finger for each person allowed to use the phone, but since there's no concept of separate people, all you'll do is make TouchID less reliable for everyone.

If the phone will only be used at home, just don't enable TouchID and be careful not to store any financial or private information on the phone.

Comment: Thank you. I'll disable TouchID, since it really will just be for home.